# How to self submitting Form in Symfony?

Tags: php, jquery, symfony-1.4

I have a symfony Form into a Template:

**Template.php**

```
<form class="well" action="<?php echo url_for("@submitParam?param=".$con) ?>" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="param">
  <button type="submit" class="thisBtn">Button</button>
</form>
```

How can i pass a value from the HTML Input `name="param"` to the url or to the variable `$con` with **jquery**, **javascript** or with any other Ways(**symfony** or **php**) when pressing on the Submit Button?

**Update :**
You can also do it with AJAX:

```
$(".btn").live('click', function(){
        $.post("<?php echo url_for('@submitParam'); ?>", $('.box').serialize(), function(response) {
            switch(response.status) {
                case 'success':
                    console.log("Success");
                    break;
                case 'failure':
                    console.log("Failure");
                    break;
            }
        }, 'json');
        return false;
    });
```

**Action :**

```
$request->getParameter('param');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to send `param` value in url, use submit button

```
<input type="submit" class="thisBtn" value="button"/>
```

and change method to get

`method="get"`

Comment: Okay Thanks! i will try it!! is not there a method with Post?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this? You already have the value of `param` because it is a input element in the form.

Comment: Hi! i want to pass the value of the input `param` to the url! self submitting!

Comment: @trouble So why do you want this? You could get the value with out append it to the url.

Comment: and How? because i need it for my Controller! i want my controller `executeSubmitParam` to save the `param` into the Database.

Comment: @trouble Shouldn't be `$request->getParameter('param')` in your controller?